# Given a Date/Time as a string, what is the best way to know if it was DST at that time?

Tags: c++, c, date, time, dst

Let's say I'm given a string such as this: `"2009-4-9"`, meaning April 9th, 2009. Assuming for starters, that I am only concerned with local time (I have concerns about other time zones as well, but I'll tackle the easy stuff first). What is the best way to know if Daylight Savings was in effect at that time?

You can assume that the system has the properly updated timezone files such as `/etc/localtime` and I am interested in portable solutions. Either c or c++ are acceptable as well.

You can also assume that I only care about past or present dates, never the future.

Currently I have a "hack" which looks like this (I know localtime_r is a library extension, but it's close enough to the same functionality that I can make it portable)

```
struct tm tm;
// convert the time string to a broken down structure in localtime
if(strptime("2009-4-9", "%Y-%m-%d", &tm)) {
    // convert the broken down structure into seconds since epoch
    const time_t t = mktime(&tm);

    // convert it back to a broken down structure, this seems pointless at first...
    // but libc will fill out fields such as tm_isdst
    localtime_r(&t, &tm);

    printf("DST : %d\n", tm.tm_isdst);
}
```

While this works (and seems to be a pretty effective way), I feel like it's silly to be converting back and forth. Is there a better way?

Comment: What time of day do you care about? It could be one offset at the start of the day and another at the end of the day...

Comment: @JonSkeet: good good question, you can assume any time of day. Which I'm sure further complicates the problem... Realistically, times around standard business hours is the common use case.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to call `localtime_r()` at all.  `mktime()` normalises the `struct tm` that you pass it, including setting `tm_isdst` to a nonnegative value if it was passed in set to `-1`.  So all you need is:

```
struct tm tm = { 0 };
// convert the time string to a broken down structure in localtime
if(strptime("2009-4-9", "%Y-%m-%d", &tm)) {
    tm.tm_isdst = -1;
    // normalise the broken down structure - this calculates tm_isdst
    mktime(&tm);

    printf("DST : %d\n", tm.tm_isdst);
}
```

This behaviour of `mktime()` is required by the C standard; for example, C99 says:

> The `mktime` function converts the broken-down time, expressed as
>   local time, in the structure pointed to by `timeptr` into a calendar
>   time value with the same encoding as that of the values returned by
>   the `time` function. The original values of the `tm_wday` and
>   `tm_yday` components of the structure are ignored, and the original
>   values of the other components are not restricted to the ranges
>   indicated above.<sup>276</sup> On successful completion, the values of
>   the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` components of the structure are set
>   appropriately, and the other components are set to represent the
>   specified calendar time, but with their values forced to the ranges
>   indicated above; the final value of `tm_mday` is not set until
>   `tm_mon` and `tm_year` are determined.

with footnote 276 explicitly addressing the `tm_isdst` member:

> 276) Thus, a positive or zero value for `tm_isdst` causes the `mktime`
>   function to presume initially that Daylight Saving Time, respectively,
>   is or is not in effect for the specified time. A negative value causes
>   it to attempt to determine whether Daylight Saving Time is in effect
>   for the specified time.

Comment: is this documented and/or standard behavior? or is it just a side effect? If it is standard behavior, please share your sources.

Comment: @EvanTeran: It is required by the C standard; I have updated the answer to include the relevant section.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from UTC to local time is *not* a reversible function. For example, in the autumn when the clocks jump back an hour, the local times between 02:00 and 03:00 occur twice. Given a time in this interval, it's *not* possible to determine whether the local time happened at a specific UTC time in local *daylight* time, or one hour later in local *standard* time.

Comment: The question appears to concern dates only, I assume this would be midnight on that date. I think DST transitions specifically avoid the midnight hour.

Comment: That's a good point that I hadn't thought of. For the purposes of my needs this would likely be considered an acceptable case because the times in question are usually around business hours.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Think again. Brazil's transition is at midnight, for example. You shouldn't assume that midnight always exists - or that it only happens once.

Comment: @MarkRansom: unfortunately I am concerned about times as well. :-/

Comment: @EvanTeran, thanks for clearing that up - my assumption of midnight would be completely wrong then, as it is before the business day.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you should know. Thanks for the counter-example. Are you aware of any locations that put the transition during an awkward time in the middle of the day?

Comment: @MarkRansom: I've just run that "query" via Noda Time, and there are some examples, yes. Juba and Khartoum both had transitions at 1pm on January 15th 2000. Those are the closest to midday, but there are plenty of other examples where people would be awake. Easter Island's transitions look like they're 10pm->11pm and 10pm->9pm local time, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I have done many time conversions before in C and I think you pretty much have it the way I would have done it too.  As far as I know, localtime_r and its relatives may be your only option (unless there is some third party date library.)  Of course, Greg Hewgill is correct for the "gray hour" between time switches.